# Can import bitmap to fingerPaint Activity?

Tags: android, bitmap, draw

I want to create activity that can import bitmap and paint on bitmap.
Now I can import but I can't paint on bitmap.

```
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        //mCanvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //canvas.drawColor(0xffffffff);

        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you try to paint?

Comment: paint path show awhile.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment "paint path show awhile", I'm guessing that the user's paint shows up but soon disappears. This is because you are constantly redrawing your bitmap over the users drawings. Add a boolean check to make sure you only paint your bitmap once:

```
Boolean first = true;

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    if(first) canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    first = false;
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```